# How to show the Annotation links on pdfJs

Tags: pdf.js

I have implement the pdfjs library to show the pdf in my application.
I have shown the pdf successfully. But the links on the pdf are not clickable. As i want o click the links to visit on the link.

pdf vsrsion : 2.10.377

Below is my code hope you will understand.

```html
   <div id="canvasPDFViewer" class="canvasPDFViewer"></div>
   <div  class="annotationLayer" id=”annotation-layer”></div>
```

This is the js I have include.

```html
<script defer>
    window.pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '/_js/pdf.worker.min.js';
</script>
```

This is the code how i am showing the pdf, the pdf is visible but, the links are not clickable.

```js
let loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);

loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
    let totalPageNumber = pdf.numPages;
    for(let pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= totalPageNumber; pageNumber++) {
        pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
        
            let scale = 1;
            let viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale }); // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
            let canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); // Render PDF page into canvas context
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;
        
            let canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
            let renderContext = {
                canvasContext: canvasContext,
                viewport: viewport
            };
            //page.render(renderContext);
            page.render(renderContext).promise.then(function() {
            return page.getAnnotations();
            }).then(function(annotationData) {
                if(annotationData.length == 0)
                return;
                 var pdf_canvas = $(canvas).offset(); 
                  $("#annotation-layer").css({ left: pdf_canvas.left + "px", top: pdf_canvas.top +          "px", height: pdf_canvas + "px", width: pdf_canvas + "px" });
                  
                  pdfjsLib.AnnotationLayer.render({
                        viewport: viewport.clone({ dontFlip: true }),
                        div: $("#annotation-layer").get(0),
                        annotations: annotationData,
                        page: page
                    });
            });
            document.getElementById("canvasPDFViewer").appendChild(canvas);
            
        });
    }
}, function (reason) {
  // PDF loading error
  // console.error(reason);
});
```

And the error is i am getting.

```
pdf.min.js:22 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'externalLinkTarget')
    at LinkAnnotationElement.render (pdf.min.js:22:1)
    at Function.render (pdf.min.js:22:1)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:1), <anonymous>:32:48)
```

Why i am getting the error.

I have tried the solution with below link.
[https://usefulangle.com/post/94/javascript-pdfjs-enable-annotation-layer]

But no luck.

Comment: anyone who can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar problem, I believe when using the `pdfjsLib.AnnotationLayer.render`, the `linkService` parameter would have to be provided, see https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/annotation_layer.js#L2611

For an example, see https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/components/simpleviewer.js#L44

However, the `EventBus` and `PDFLinkService` are defined in the pdf viewer, not in `window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf']`. I do believe to get those, you'll have to import `web/pdf_viewer.js` besides `build/pdf.js` (assuming you're using https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist), now you can access those two classes on `window["pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer"]`.

---

I'm at the moment simply filtering out all link annotations, as I only need forms anyway:

```js
pdfjsLib.AnnotationLayer.render({
    viewport: viewport, //.clone({ dontFlip: true }),
    div: $("#annotation-layer").get(0),
    annotations: annotationData.filter(o => o.subtype !== 'Link'),
    page: page
});
```